# web table linked service in azure data factory

Tags: dataset, azure-data-factory, linked-service

Does anyone know what does an index in Web table dataset mean?How should we give one, when i try to gave 1, its throwing an error while previewing data .

The value of the property 'index' is invalid: 'The required property is not specified.
Parameter name: index'.
The required property is not specified.
Parameter name: index

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRiCm.png)

Comment: you can get the index of table from excel follow this Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-web-table?tabs=data-factory#get-index-of-a-table-in-an-html-page). now this index no you can use to fetch desired table from your URL.

Comment: i tried this and i am getting is the html response of the page

Comment: number next to "Source" is your Index for the table which you can use In Index.

Comment: I tried in my environment, and it is working fine for me. with above document.